# Como posso finalizar um setInterval?

Tags: javascript

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível parar um setinterval após certo tempo, caso seja possível, como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível, você precisará trabalhar com a função clearInterval.

```js
let qtd = 0;

let interval = setInterval( () => {
  console.log("Entrando...");
  qtd++;

  if (qtd == 5) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000 );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Answer (score 2):

Só utilizaro `clearInterval()`
Exemplo:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
```